# Change textbox value in usercontrol from window form

Tags: c#-5.0

I wish to change the value of the textbox in user control from another window form in my application. I’ve tried doing it like this:

```
Usercontrol uc = new usercontrol ();
uc.Textbox.text = “hello”;
```

But it doesn’t change the value on the textbox. But if I display the textbox value in the message box I can see it has changed. Please what can be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

In your first form create a public string

```
public static string myValue="";

//set a value
myValue = "hello";
```

Second do this in your second Form in `formLoad` or under `IntializeComponent();`

```
textBox.Text = Form1.myValue
```